# Pass Variable to be Expanded in MAKEFLAGS

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, bsdmake

Given a Makefile like below, how can I set the value of `FOOBAR` to `foo /home/scott` using `$MAKEFLAGS`?

```
FOO=foo
FOOBAR=$(FOO) bar

$(info $$FOOBAR is [$(FOOBAR)])
```

I know I can do

```sh
$ make FOOBAR="\$(FOO) $HOME"
$FOOBAR is [foo /home/scott]
```

And this works fine

```
$ MAKEFLAGS="FOOBAR=foo\ $HOME" make
$FOOBAR is [foo /home/scott]
```

Interestingly, this doesn't work so well

```sh
$ MAKEFLAGS="FOOBAR='foo $HOME'" make
$FOOBAR is ['foo]
```

My goal is something like this, but try as I might I cannot make it happen

```sh
$ export MAKEFLAGS="FOOBAR=\$(FOO)\ $HOME"  # <-- this line is wrong
$ make
$FOOBAR is [foo /home/scott]  # <-- not the real output
```

Actual output of that is

```sh
$ export MAKEFLAGS="FOOBAR=\$(FOO)\ $HOME"
$ make
$FOOBAR is [/home/scott]
```

How can I use a variable to be substituted in a `$MAKEFLAGS` override?

(A POSIX standard solution is preferred, but a GNU-only solution would work.)

(Why do I need this? I want to override a variable used by Python which I am building with pyenv's python-build. I found that python-build exposes `$MAKE_OPTS` which turned out to work, but now I'm curious why my previous attempts have failed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `MAKEFLAGS` are immediately substituted, so before your `FOO` is even defined and as such it resolves to an empty string. If you wish to postpone resolution, you would need to double the dollar, e.g.:

```
$ export MAKEFLAGS="FOOBAR=\$\$(FOO)\ $HOME"
$ make
$FOOBAR is [foo /home/raspy]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your help!